# Making a div into a button that changes color when I press it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a div into a button with a background that changes color when I mouse over and another color when I press it. What I want to do is have the button behave like a link that takes me to another page when I press it.

Can you tell me if this is simple to do. How do I make the colors change?  If you have any example I would really be thankful for your help.

Comment: What not just style an `a` element?

Comment: I would like to style an <a> but i am not sure how. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the `<div>` doesn't contain any interactive content (for example, a link or a `<button>` element), you can do something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com">
  <div id="awesomediv">Foo</div>
</a>
```

Then use the CSS pseudo-classes `:hover` and `:active` to style the `<div>` element:

```
a:hover #awesomediv {
  background-color: green;
}

a:active #awesomediv {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Which would make the `<div>` element turn green when you hover over it and turn blue when clicked.

Comment: I tried this and it says HTML5. Div element cannot be nested within element a

Comment: @Kiyoshi Validators are dumb: they don't fully understand the complexities of a specification. `<div>` elements can be nested within `<a>` elements as long as they don't contain interactive content. See [the note at the example in the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element) (just before the definition of the `<em>` element): "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)."